# SWIFT - FBSDKLoginManager error when using FB App

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, ios11, fbsdkloginkit

I'm using the `FBSDKLoginManager` to receive a token for later usage (FB posting) and end up in an **endless loop after confirming the access.**

When calling the `FBSDKLoginManager()`, the following popup appears (Sorry, it's in German language... This is the official Facebook popup, where the user can select whether he wants to logon manually or using the FB App).

[image: Facebook Popup Screen]

Now the following error occurs:

- If I'm using the second button (logon via phone number or E-Mail-Address), everything works fine. The function returns with a token and I can go on in my App.
- **The ERROR:** If I'm using the first button (logon with Facebook-App), the Facebook App opens, I can set all the privacy settings in FB, and confirm. After confirming the access, the FB-App closes automatically and returns to the same popup-screen without any change. No action occurs after coming back to this screen...

I don't have any foggy idea where the problem is... There is no error message. Due to the fact that everything works fine when using the E-Mail Login, the problem must be in the return of the FB-App. The E-Mail Login works via Safari, in the error case there is the break to the FB-App.

```
let login: FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
login.logIn(withPublishPermissions: ["publish_actions"], from: self) { (result, error) in
if (error != nil) {
    print("publish_actions: \(error!)")
} else if (result?.isCancelled)! {
    print("publish_actions: Canceled")
} else if (result?.grantedPermissions.contains("publish_actions"))! {
    //print("publish_actions: permissions granted: \(String(describing: result?.token.tokenString))")

    UserDefaults.standard.set(result?.token.tokenString, forKey: "facebook_token")
}
```

Added Frameworks: `Bolts / CoreKit / LoginKit`

*Development Environment:* Xcode 9.2 / iPhone 6s with iOS 11.2 / latest Facebook App installed.

Answer (score 1):

I solved by adding the follow missing call to FB SDK:

```
[[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
```

inside

`-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation` method of the AppDelegate.

Comment: Thanks man. One year without using the library has these problems.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. This doesn't solved the issue. Can you please help me solving this weird behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Check for following
in your info plist file

```
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>fb_id_here</string> // in format 234234234
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>display_name_here</string>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>

</array>
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fbfb_id_here </string>. // in format fb234234234
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

now inyour appdelegate

in

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
 SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {

    if let scheme = url.scheme {

        if scheme == "fb 234234234" { //the one you kept in your info plist file
            //TODO: replace with real value
            return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, open: url, options: options)
        }

    }

    return true

}
```

Do configure these and then dub your app, if the control folw comes in appdelegate function

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool
```

if it doesnt you have not configured facebook schemas correctly in info plist file

also

```
let fbManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
fbManager.logOut()

    let readPermissions: [ReadPermission] = [.publicProfile, .email]
    let sdkPermissions = readPermissions.map({ $0.permissionValue.name })

    fbManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: sdkPermissions, from: nil) { (result, error) in
        if let token = result?.token {
            // your token here
        }
        else {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much. This solved the problem.

1.) The plist file was already set up. I think otherwise the login with Safari wouldn't have worked.

2.) The App Delegate was the reason!!! Small adjustment:

`SDKApplicationDelegate.shared` didn't work. I should be as followed:

```
FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
```

(As well in the added "application-open URL"-function.)

But now it works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

i think maybe i found an one issue, in my xcode, AppDelegate's 
`func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool` , xcode fix this function to `private`, and i fixed this function to `internal`, it will works~